# N1ql query to filter by two fields in couchbase database

Tags: spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, sql++

I created a web service using springboot and reactive couchbase,in the repository interface i want to add two fields to the WHERE clause. What I did is below

```
@ViewIndexed(designDoc = "enrolment")
@N1qlPrimaryIndexed
public interface EnrolmentRepository extends ReactiveCouchbaseRepository<Enrolment,String> {
    @Query("#{#n1ql.selectEntity} where #{#n1ql.filter} and course like $1 and role like $2 within #{#n1ql.bucket}")
    Mono<Enrolment> findEnrolmentByCourseRole(String course, String role);
}
```

But when use the above code, I get response as ,

```
{
   "timestamp": "2019-06-14T03:57:29.670+0000",
   "path": "/enrolments",
   "status": 500,
   "error": "Internal Server Error",
   "message": "Unable to execute n1ql query due to error:{"msg":"syntax error - at role","code":3000}"
}
```

My endpoint is,

```
http://localhost:8783/enrolments?course=testcourse&role=testrole
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine after changed as below.

```
@Query("#{#n1ql.selectEntity} where #{#n1ql.filter} and enrolledCourse = $1 and enrolledRole = $2")
Mono<Enrolment> findEnrolmentByCourseRole(String enrolledCourse, String enrolledRole);
```

Seems the error was with the variable name "role"; changed everywhere to "enrolledRole".It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

role is reserved keyword as described here https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/reservedwords.html

You can use back-ticks escape identifiers

Example :

```
 SELECT *
 FROM default
 WHERE `role` = "xyz";
```

Comment: yes, avoiding reserved keywords made the endpoint work without errors